# Insert message in tkinter text box not visible

Tags: python-3.x, function, tkinter

I have been having an issue with getting python to complete a command and insert it in a text box before it continues to what follows that line of code. I wrote a script using a generator (see the "work" function), my code is below:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
import time


def work(given_string):
    send_receive = yield given_string
    new_string = given_string + " Received, You did it!! :-D"

    yield new_string


def contains_word(s, w):
    return((' ' + w + ' ') in (' ' + s + ' '))


def close_window():
    window.destroy()
    exit()
```

The above functions are called in the functions that follow. The "contains_word" function checks if the string w is in s. The "on_click" function that follows is called as a command in the "main_fun" submit button.

```
def on_click(output):
    # this generates the object that will be just for the function call:
    result_obj = work(" john ")

    # first function call, until first yield statement:
    result_1 = next(result_obj)

    output.insert(END, result_1)

    time.sleep(3)   # Delays for 3 seconds. You can also use a float value.

    if (contains_word(output.get(1.0, "end-1c"), "john") == TRUE):
        # second function call...
        result_2 = result_obj.send("john sent back to function")
        output.delete(1.10, "end-1c")
        output.insert(END, result_2 +
                      "\n" + "All commands completed")


def main_fun():

    global exit_button, window, output, x_ref, v
    window = tkinter.Tk()
    window.geometry("400x200")  # Width x Height
    v = IntVar()

    output = Text(window, width=40, height=5, wrap=WORD, background="white")
    output.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W)

    submit_button = Button(window, text="SUBMIT", width=6,
                           command=lambda: on_click(output))
    submit_button.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)

    x_ref = 13
    exit_button = Button(window, text="Exit", width=14, command=close_window)
    exit_button.grid(row=x_ref, column=0, sticky=W)

    window.mainloop()


main_fun()
```

Put simply, my problem here is that after "output.insert(END, result_1)" is executed it is not visible in the "output" tkinter object before the content of the if statement that follows is executed.

I tried using a time delay, however this didn't work and the issue still persists.

Even stranger is the fact that the content of the if statement executes. Therefore the text is in the "output" object but I just don't see it. Please assist.

Comment: Try adding `output.update()` before `time.sleep(...)` inside `on_click(...)` function.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I have been struggling to get this to work for DAYS now. I really appreciate it.